# react-Router nested rouths refresh error with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

When i use the `Link to="/Home/PageA"`   It is work well, but when i refresh the page or typing "/Home/PageA" in brower,the bundle will error.

It is has some conflict between WebPack and React-Router?And how to fix it?

Thx in Advance.

**here is my pic Explain**

[actPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym89y.png)
[errorPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMDyX.png)

**here is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory, Link } from 'react-router'

    const App = (props) => {
        console.log("App", props);
        const key = 'root';
        return (
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(props.children || <div />, { key })}
            </div>
        );
    };


    const LoginPage = (props) => {
        console.log("Login", props);

        return (
            <div className="Image">
                <h1>this is LoginPage</h1>
            </div>
        );
    };

    const HomePage = (props) => {
        console.log("Home", props);
        return (
            <div className="Image">
                <li><Link to="/Home/PageA">Tab 1</Link></li>
                <h1>this is  Home page</h1>
                {React.cloneElement(props.children || <div />, { key: props.pathname })}
            </div>
        );
    };

    const PageA = (props) => {
        console.log("pageA", props);
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='button' value="back" onClick={props.router.goBack}></input>
                this is pageA;
            </div>
        );
    };



    ReactDOM.render((
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="Login" component={LoginPage}>
                </Route>[enter image description here][1]
                <Route path="Home" component={HomePage}>
                    <Route path="PageA" component={PageA}>
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>

    ), document.getElementById('container'));
```

**here is my webPack.config**

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map', 
    entry: __dirname + "/app/app.js", 
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/app", 
        filename: "bundle.js" 
    },
    module: { 
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json"
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel', 
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css' 
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=25000'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: "9023",
        contentBase: "./app", 
        colors: true, 
        historyApiFallback: true, 
        inline: true 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should webpack dev server as Lukas answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's about rendering on serverside. You need to have server side mapping path with router object. Check out [WebpackDevServer](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

You use browserHistory by default and you can read more here how to configure it properly:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

Or use hash history, it's easier to get done:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory

Comment: i have no idea ,can you explain more detail?

Comment: Your server must be configured to route all routes to your index.html or if that doesn't help in your situation you have to write some server which will map requested url with react's router. Or you can use hashtag history and forget about all this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory